# Render Container to a hidden div and then set visible fails

Tags: javascript, extjs

It seems like there is a bug in ExtJS 6. The problem is reproduced just with a little bit of code in this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1up9). So, we have a `div` with `display=none`:

```
<div id="btn"></div>
<div style="display:none" id="outer_container">
    <div id="test_container"></div>
</div>
```

We then render `Button` to `btn` div and `Component` to `test_container` like so:

```
var id = Ext.id();
Ext.create("Ext.Button",{
    text: "show",
    renderTo: "btn",
    handler: function (){
        document.getElementById("outer_container").style.display = "block";
        //Ext.getCmp(id).setVisible(true) // does not help
    }
});
Ext.create("Ext.container.Container", {
    renderTo: "test_container",
    width:"400",
    border:"1",
    id: id,
    style:{
        borderColor:"#000000",
        borderStyle:"solid",
        borderWidth:"1px"
    },
    layout:{type:"hbox"},
    defaults:{labelWidth:"80"},
    items:[
        {"xtype":"numberfield", "name":"attr_1_"},{"xtype":"datefield","startDay":"1","format":"d.m.Y","name":"attr_2_"}
    ]
});
```

If we then click on the button to make our component visible, we will see just a gray line and if we inspect the DOM we will also see, that component has zero height and width. What is the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not bound to use `Ext.container.Container` you could use `Ext.panel.Panel`. The panel component seems to attach style information correct after calling `updateLayout`.

Nevertheless, after clicking the button in your handler you have to update the layout.

```
var id = Ext.id();
        Ext.create("Ext.Button",{
            text: "show",
            renderTo: "btn",
            handler: function (){
                document.getElementById("outer_container").style.display = "block";
                Ext.getCmp(id).updateLayout();
            }
        });
        Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
            renderTo: "test_container",
            width:400,
            visible:true,
            id : id,
            border:"1",
            style:{
                borderColor:"#000000",
                borderStyle:"solid",
                borderWidth:"1px"
            },
            layout:{type:"hbox"},
            defaults:{labelWidth:"80"},
            items:[
                {"xtype":"numberfield", "name":"attr_1_"},
                {"xtype":"datefield","startDay":"1","format":"d.m.Y","name":"attr_2_"}
            ]
        });
```

Comment: BTW, I do not need to call any updateLayout method, if I use standard Form fields. If, say, I render a field in a hidden div and then show it - its ok, So, it seems like Container has a bug.

Comment: In other words, `Ext.Panel` also seems to have a bug, because when it comes to standard fields there is no need to make any extra work (updateLayout I mean).

Comment: I am not sure if its a bug. If you use visible:false on the component and not setting the div via style to hidden it works perfectly (after calling setVisible(true) :) ). ExtJS may just do not know when the visibility changes of the outer div since its not ExtJS managed and thus layout events are not thrown.

Comment: "ExtJS may just do not know". Exactly! But still adds zero height and width if parent component has display=none. It seems like it takes into account that parent component has some style, but does not take into account when this style changes. So, it's a kind of incomplete behaviour.